# Create custom migration script for bootstrap data and for performing some SQL related operations in Grails

Tags: grails, migration

I am working on a Grails project. In this I need to do two things related **Migration Scripts** as follows :

1. I made a script for boot strap data and also having BootStrap.groovy for boot strap data. My Code of Both scripts is as follows :

   [BootStrape.groovy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/84sxfkyy5s3tja4/BootStrapeTxt.txt)

   [Mine DatabaseInit.groovy Script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6u8dwyemmwbmkii/DataBaseInit.txt.txt)

   Now I want to implement(or move the code of) both of these scripts in my **migration script**. How to achieve that, please give me some hint.
2. I need to do some SQL operations for removing some duplicate values from database as follow

   ```
   UPDATE DatabaseName.TableName1 SET ColumName = 2 WHERE ColumName IN (
   SELECT ColumName FROM DatabaseName.TableName2 st WHERE st.ColumName = 'XYZ');

   DELETE FROM DatabaseName.TableName2 WHERE ColumName NOT IN (2);
   ```

   How to write **migration script** for achieving this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a advisable idea that you keep your bootstrap file tiny ...no too much code inside and that good approach to follow , yours.

So , what you need is try to create a `new migration scrip` `file` even if you didn't have a change in your `DOMAIN` . Since ,this will help you add your sql script and then later will not execute them at every start up if they are once successfully created.

TODO on grails command line :

```
grails dbm-create-changelog
grails prod dbm-generate-gorm-changelog --add changelog-1.0.whatevername.groovy
```

Then ,

add the sql script inside `changelog-1.0.whatevername.groovy` file as follow :

```
1.Using sql file like 

    //sqlFile( path: "${ path to SQL file relative to changelog.groovy }")
    //Used in a changeset, it looks like this:
    changeSet(author: "username", id: "1305821637932-1") { //id:is to be changed
      sqlFile( path: "books.sql")
    }
```

2.Using by writing the scrip inside

```
changeSet(author: "username", id: "1305821637932-2") {  //id : is to be changed
  addColumn(tableName: "book") {
    column(name: "flammable", type: "BIT") {
       constraints(nullable: "false")
    }
  }
  SQL("UPDATE DatabaseName.TableName1 SET ColumName = 2 WHERE ColumName IN (
  SELECT ColumName FROM DatabaseName.TableName2 st WHERE st.ColumName = 'XYZ'))";
  SQL("DELETE FROM DatabaseName.TableName2 WHERE ColumName NOT IN (2)");
}
```

Happy coding!! please refer [this](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/running-custom-sql-in-grails-database-migration-plugin-changesets/) and [this](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/17/countdown-to-grails-2-0-database-migrations/)

Comment: @danielad..Thanks for your answer. I tried to run sql query in change set as you mention above, like this : 

`changeSet(author: "admin (generated)", id: "1395990447387-82") { 
     sql("INSERT INTO status VALUES ('test')")
  
 }`

But after executing `grails dbm-changelog-sync` I am getting ` 1 change sets have changed since they were ran against the database` this error message in.

Comment: @okay ...you came near... so what you should do is increment the ID to something else and restart ...!! it is some how to assisit but ..try that and we will see...also read about checksum of script file ans how to bypass..then your answer lies there!

Comment: @danielad.. I have incremented the id already, my id is unique in that migration file. And about `checksum of script` ; Does I need to run 

`grails [environment] dbm-clear-checksums --dataSource=[dataSource]`

this command for making this work. Thanks.

Comment: @mark probabily Yes , but the thing to trick is to cheat the migration script database as nothing is changed ,since we added the native sql script after the checksum is saved and we are done!

Comment: @may be remove it from include file name from changelog.groovy  and see ?

Comment: @danielad.. Thank you so much , It worked by executing `grails dbm-clear-checksum` before executing `dbm-update`.